# How to load script files dynamically with react and gulp

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, gulp

I'm developing a gaming platform and I've chosen react as the technology on the frontend. Currently I'm building all the script files into one js file using gulp. That doesn't cause a problem, because there's only one game, but when the number of games increases, the browser will load a lot of useless code. So I'd like to have all the platform logic in a single file, and the script for each game would be built into separate files which would be loaded on the browser when they are needed. How could I reference a react class within a built and dynamically loaded file?

For example, game1 consists of 3 files, which are built into game1.js. The main file of those 3 contains a react class Game1. How would I reference that class? Normally if those were in the same bundle, I would write "var game = require('game1_main')".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If [webpack](https://webpack.github.io/) is an option for you, you could use its [codesplitting](http://webpack.github.io/docs/code-splitting.html) feature.

Comment: Thanks, I don't see any major drawbacks using webpack, and it seems that changes to existing code would be minimal. It requires some configuration to get it to work with react though. I'll accept the answer when I get it to work.